# R - Delete one row when two sequential row have the same value - How?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame whose rownames is a list of dates and it has a column of closing prices.
I want to delete the rows for which the closing price is equal to the one of the previous row.

I tried to write a code but it doesn't work and I can't understand if it is a syntax error or the code itself is completely wrong.

```
removefunction <- function(x) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    if(x[1+i] == x[i]) {
    x[1+i] <- "NA"}}
    na.omit(x)
}
```

I guess there is a problem with the selection of the value in the data.frame but I can't figure out how to solve it.

EDIT:
This is a sample of my data.frame:

```
%  row.names  Close
1  2001-01-01  1837.36
2  2001-01-02  1785.86
3  2001-01-03  1875.56
4  2001-01-04  1855.82
5  2001-01-05  1807.13
6  2001-01-08  1804.04
7  2001-01-09  1810.98
8  2001-01-10  1828.50
9  2001-01-11  1847.37
10 2001-01-12  1835.53
11 2001-01-15  1835.53
12 2001-01-16  1847.13
```

My aim is to remove row 11 because it has the same Close value as row 10.

The error is: *Error in [.data.frame(x, 1 + i) : undefined columns selected*

Comment: maybe you can try `diff` : `toremove <- c(F, diff(yourvar)==0)` will give you the indexes of the rows you want to remove

Comment: Please precise what means "it doesn't work" (error message) and give an example dataset.

Comment: `x[diff(x$closing_price)!=0, ]`

Comment: see my edit to know how to do that with your data.frame (you don't need a function for that). Your error comes from the fact that you're not selecting any column, you need to put `x[i, ]` for example to select entire i-th row .

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific than what I said in my comment, here is how to do it with `diff` with some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(v1=1:10, v2=sample(c(1, 2), 10, replace=T))
> df
#  v1 v2
#1   1  1
#2   2  2
#3   3  1
#4   4  2
#5   5  2
#6   6  1
#7   7  2
#8   8  2
#9   9  2
#10 10  1

df[c(T, diff(df$v2)!=0), ]
#   v1 v2
#1   1  1
#2   2  2
#3   3  1
#4   4  2
#6   6  1
#7   7  2
#10 10  1
```

**EDIT**
And with your data, you can do, if your data.frame is called `df`: `df[c(T, diff(df$Close)!=0), ]`